# Is it possible to trigger event that are displayed behind another pane?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So the project is a game in Java FX. There is a GridPane which is a classic board game. It displays white and black boxes and I have events on those to change the color when MouseEntered. The problem is I have another pane on that one wich contains nothing and that I use to put some ImageView on the board. I can't do this on the GridPane since the images have different size and it mess up the grid if I add them. Cutting the images would be a solution but I'd rather avoid this.
So I'm looking for a way to accomplish this. Setting the second grid as false then true is not an option neither since the image would disappear. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [setMouseTransparent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent%28boolean%29) which you can use on the front layer.